# Error when using Azure monitor data source for Grafana

Tags: grafana, azure-monitoring

I've been trying to connect Azure monitor to my Grafana dashboard, which is deployed in a Kubernetes cluster. For this I created an app registration in Azure and assigned the 'Reader' role to it. Afterwards I filled in my Azure credentials at the Azure Monitor page in Grafana. I was able to retrieve the right subscription and receive a positive response.

But after this, when I want to open a dashboard, I receive the following error message:

> Error updating options: The client '++++' with object id '++++' does
> not have authorization to perform action
> 'microsoft.insights/metricNamespaces/read' over scope
> '/subscriptions/++++/resourceGroups/++++;/providers/microsoft.insights'
> or the scope is invalid. If access was recently granted, please
> refresh your credentials

I'm really stuck now, because I thought that the Reader role would fix this. Anyone experienced this before?

I have tried to assign multiple roles and also created new ones and assigned them to the Grafana app registration. I expect the dashboard to be able to read the data from Azure. There is an connection between Azure and Grafana now, but it is not able to pull the data.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

My bad, I figured it out. I needed to assign the Reader role on the subscription level and not only on resource group level. Hopefully this will help someone else in the future.

Comment: I don't have the permission to add on the Subscription level, so I've tried adding the Monitoring Reader and Reader role to my Resource Group but I still get this message when trying to "Select a resource" in a Grafana Dashboard: 

"Unable to resolve a list of valid metric namespaces. Validate the datasource configuration is correct and required permissions have been granted for all subscriptions. Grafana requires at least the Reader role to be assigned."

Comment: @OliverNilsen as OP mentioned in the answer. You'll have to give the required permission on the subscription level to get past this error.